# Detecting ctrl + arrow keys in javascript

Tags: javascript

This seems like something that should be straight forward but I can't seem to find any combination of event listeners that will allow me to detect when a user presses ctrl + an arrow key.

I've tested this with the following code:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

I get output logged when I press ctrl or an arrow key, but while ctrl is held the arrow keys don't trigger an event.

There's a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/oat0h7jc/1/ that demonstrates this.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What browser are you using?  Ctrl + arrow keys work fine for me in your example, in Firefox.  Also, check the properties of the `e` object in each of your events, you'll see a [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey) property.

Comment: is that what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/oat0h7jc/2/ Your example can detect ctrl and arrow up. If the result of my jsfiddle is that what you want, it means you are asking why the arrow up cannot get the ctrl event.

Comment: @mplungjan - I did search, the code in those examples doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Jacky Shek - that code still doesn't work for me, I'm using chrome on a mac but I've also checked Safari / Firefox, I wonder if it's a mac thing. Are you guys on windows?

Comment: Mac is using meta

Comment: Ctrl arrow is taken by OSX

Comment: Eugh, that's annoying.

Comment: @mplungjan Totally correct. So he needs to use Command Key (Meta) https://jsfiddle.net/oat0h7jc/4/ 
I am Mac user which i just use command key rather than ctrl key.